# How to build docker image with local package inside folder with main.go?

Tags: docker, go, docker-build

I'm trying docker build -t test_1 . , but have this err:

> package docker_test/mult: unrecognized import path "docker_test/mult"
>   (import path does not begin with hostname)
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c go get -d -v ./...' returned a non-zero code: 1

My dockerfile (path  /gowork/src/Dockerfile):

```
FROM golang:1.9.1
COPY ./docker_test/mult /go/src/app

WORKDIR go/src/app
COPY ./docker_test/main.go .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
ENTRYPOINT ["app", "-f=7", "-s=9"]
```

main.go (path: gowork/src/docker_test/main.go)

```
package main

import (
    "docker_test/mult"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("From different pkg")
    mult.Multiple()
}
```

mult.go (path: gowork/src/docker_test/mult/mult.go)

```
package mult

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func Multiple() {

    first := flag.Int("f", 0, "placeholder")
    second := flag.Int("s", 0, "placeholder")

    flag.Parse()

    out := (*first) * (*second)
    fmt.Println(out)

}
```

Comment: can you try  change your 1st copy to `COPY ./docker_test /go/src/docker_test`, If it works, then I will explain in my answer why It worked.

Comment: Now error is: `go install: no install location for directory /go/go/src/app outside GOPATH
 For more details see: 'go help gopath'
The command '/bin/sh -c go install -v ./...' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`go get` trying to find the package `docker_test/mult` into `/go` path. But, you have copied into `/go/src/app`. That's why `go get` can't find the package locally and assumes the package is from remote repository, eg, github, and throws error `import path does not begin with hostname`. So copy the `docker_test/mult` inside `/go` path.

Another concern is, when you use `WORKDIR go/src/app`, it creates `go/src/app` inside `/go` path, So finally the path becomes `/go/go/src/app`. So use absolute path ie, `WORKDIR /go/src/app`.

Try this `dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.9.1
COPY ./docker_test/mult /go/src/docker_test/mult

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY ./docker_test/main.go .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
ENTRYPOINT ["app", "-f=7", "-s=9"]
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Can you explain why..? I mean, I thought that this way (`COPY ./docker_test /go/src/docker_test`) I copied all files, includes main.go in docker_test...

Comment: @Mitch. I was still adding some concepts, while you tried. :) I now added the explanation. Does the changes makes sense?

Comment: Yep, it's more clearly, thanks, but still doesn't understand why after COPY ./docker_test /go/src/docker_test AND copying main.go I don't have 2 main.go files in project(

Comment: @Mitch, that&'s a good catch. Yes there will be one extra main.go file inside `/go/src/docker_test`, but it is not creating problem because that file doesn't belong to any of project directory (`workdir`) or dependency folders. Although, it should not be copied. I overlooked it. The 1st copy should have been, `COPY ./docker_test/mult /go/src/docker_test/mult `

Comment: Dockerfile needs to be in parent folder of the files you are trying to `Copy`. But, it is possible to keep dockerfile in seperate folder. In that case, your pointer needs to be in any parent folder of the files, then provide the the docker file location with `file` flag. So, in your case,  from `src` folder, you can run this command: `docker build -t example-tag . -f builder/Dockerfile`

Comment: Thaanks again for answer )) I've tried it, thought maybe there's a way to do it from dockerfile, but it's not bad too

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the GOPATH, in your example import uses docker_test/mult, so in order compiler to resolve it place it into $GOPATH/docker_test/mult,

I have tweaked your Dockerfile, so you should be able to buld it

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.9.1

ENV GOPATH /go

FROM golang:1.9.1
COPY ./docker_test /go/src/docker_test
COPY ./docker_test/main.go /go/src/app/main.go

WORKDIR /go/src/app

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...


CMD ["app"]
ENTRYPOINT ["app", "-f=7", "-s=9"]
```